# dynamic vue-router base on webpack applications

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Good day.

**Problem definition:**

I would like to deploy my Vue app, that utilizes vue-router, on dynamic path, which should be controlled by the WebServer, utilize vue-router in history mode, and avoid re-packaging the application for each Deployment.

*F.e.*

Run same app at
http://localhost/subpath/index.html
and
http://localhost/another-subpath/index.html

As **vue-router** configuration is done at the packaging stage (f.e. by webpack), and thus is not designed to be controlled after the packaging stage, making this simple but so-common setup not viable.

Also, **vue-router** have quite a complicated lifecycle, which does not allow to easily override that **base** setting at the application-level.

In addition - `webpack` ends up hardcoding actual resources into the `html` body, which ensures their proper consumption by the Client at the load-time, but as chunks are inter-dependent - they are almost impossible to be injected/edited dynamically. Application integrity fails in case of any modification to those on-post-DomReady event.

**Research:**
My search so far have not yielded any viable options to set such configuration up.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a couple of viable solutions.

---

One of the problems is that changing the Router Base is not the only thing one needs, in order to dynamically change the App's root, and make it function properly on dynamic URL.

In case of vue+webpack - actual scripts are added to the `index.html` on-build-stage, and thus - again - end up being hardcoded.

There are few options of fixing that, which I came up with.

## The Ugly solution:

Regex-replace resources URLs at the `index.html`, on the web-server level, and hardcoded setting for your vue-router-base.

This is very questionable approach, but viable.

Unfortunately I do not have examples of that approach left, so - I can't provide any, but this should be pretty straightforward:

On your servlet-side, Pseudocode:

```js
let fileContent = getFileContent(requested_file_name);
if (servingFile == "index.html") {
  fileContent = fileContent.regexReplace("http://url_hardcoded_at_packaging_stage", "http://url_application_is_deployed_at");
  fileContent = fileContent.regexReplace("setting_token_in_your_index_html", "http://url_application_is_deployed_at");
}
return fileContent;
```

In addition to that you will need to add this `setting_token_in_your_index_html` in your `index.html`:

```js
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.my_app_settings = {routerBase:"setting_token_in_your_index_html"}
</script>
</head>
```

And consume it at the vue-router level:

```js
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: window.my_app_settings.routerBase,
  routes: [...]
  ...
});
```

This approach is good in a sense that there is no need to modify anything on your vue-app level, and all the changes can be kept only on your servlet-side, whatever it is.

Also it has 0 performance impact on the vue-app itself.

## Still ugly, but a lots better, from code-perspective at least:

Make **vue-app** **base**-aware.

This solution is not super-simple, but works reliably on all major web-servers and can be summarized as
**Dynamically add vue-resources at the app init, based on cookie provided by the Web-Server**.

This approach allows to "elegantly" modify all the resources URLs, with minimum impact on the performance-side, and keep things as dynamic as they can be.

This approach consists of few small changes on the Packaging, and the app-levels, and also relies on `cookie` to inform the app about custom base.

**Provide the custom URL cookie from Server:**

At your web-server add the cookie header (all major web-servers support such functionality):

(f.e. in Scalatra)

```java
val contextShiftCookie = "subpath_where_ui_deployed";
val cookie = new Cookie("ui_deployment_root", contextShiftCookie );
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie( cookie );
```

**App modifications (`index.html`):**

At the `<head>` section:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Build script names, for later injection.
      let stringsJs = [
      <% for (let js in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) { %>
        "<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[js] %>",
      <% } %>
      ];
      let stringsCss = [
      <% for (let css in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
        "<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css] %>",
      <% } %>
      ];
      // Simple vanilla Cookie getter (replace with something else if needed).
      function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }
        }
        return "";
      }
      // Simple vanilla onDomReady handler (replace with something else if needed).
      (function(exports, d) {
        function domReady(fn, context) {
          function onReady(event) {
            d.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onReady);
            fn.call(context || exports, event);
          }
          function onReadyIe(event) {
            if (d.readyState === "complete") {
              d.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", onReadyIe);
              fn.call(context || exports, event);
            }
          }
            d.addEventListener && d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onReady) ||
            d.attachEvent      && d.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", onReadyIe);
          }
          exports.domReady = domReady;
      })(window, document);

      // Calculating vue router base.
      let routerBase = "/";
      if (getCookie("ui_deployment_root")) {
        routerBase = getCookie("ui_deployment_root");
        // console.log("Found base cookie", routerBase);
      } else {
        console.log("No base cookie found");
      }
      let scriptsBase = routerBase == "/"? "" : routerBase;

      // Prefilling basic settings.
      window.my_vue_app_config = {
        routerBase: routerBase
      };

      function loadOneScript(){
          if (window.my_vue_app_scripts.length > 0) {
            let currentScript = window.my_vue_app_scripts.shift();
            currentScript.onload = loadOneScript;
            document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0).append(currentScript);
          }
        }

      // Injecting scripts using deployment context.
      domReady(function(event) {
        let head = document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);
        stringsCss.forEach(css => {
          let script = document.createElement("link");
          script.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
          script.setAttribute("href", scriptsBase + css);
          head.append(script);
        });
        window.my_vue_app_scripts = [];
        stringsJs.forEach(js => {
          let script = document.createElement("script");
          script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
          script.setAttribute("src", scriptsBase + js);
          window.my_vue_app_scripts.push(script);
        });
        loadOneScript();
      });
    </script>
```

*Step-by-step* explanation:

0. Consume `base` setting as-soon-as-it-is-available, **BEFORE** actual chunks are loaded, to ensure that `vue-router` can consume it nicely.
1. Gather all the script names from WebPack (see `let stringsJs` and `let stringsCss`)
2. Load all the `css` as soon as the DomReady (because `css` is consumed on-the-fly, and there is nothing specific about loading them. They just should be available). See `stringsCss.forEach` for that.
3. Load all the `js` chunks one-by-one, as this is the only way to ensure that webpack-ed app will be initialized properly (see `stringsJs.forEach`, and `loadOneScript` routine).

- Scripts loading is done in such manner that each script (chunk) requests another chunk as soon as it is loaded and consumed by the Client (browser). This ensures app integrity, and proper initialization, regardless of how it was packed.
- Chunks are processed in proper order, provided by the webpack, again - to ensure integrity.

**vue-router changes:**

Consume new setting at the router-level:

```js
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: window.my_vue_app_config.routerBase,
  routes: [...]
  ...
});
```

**Webpack mechanism changes:**

To support custom bundling at the webpack:

```js
<% for (let js in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) { %>
  "<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[js] %>",
<% } %>
```

, you will need to modify the `/app/build/webpack.ENV.conf.js` file:

```js
...
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    ...
    inject: false,
    ...
}),
```

Where `.ENV.` should be your desired bundle target, but I suggest changing this for all your environments, as then you will be sure that your `index.html` changes work properly on all Environments.

**Performance considerations:**

This was my biggest concern with this "sequential scripts injection", because it sounds very bad, from performance perspective.

But, to my biggest surprise, actual tests have shown only ~`0.100-0.150`ms raize in the `JavaScript processing time`, compared to the fully-static serve of the Application, according to tests on all major Web Clients (browsers).

This basically renders performance concern irrelevant in my case, but we wary that this might differ in your case.

Other impact on the application lifecycle is totally neglectable, at least in my case (less than `0.05`ms in overall impact on the App Load).

---

P.S.

As this approach is something I've developed purely myself - I would appreciate constructive criticism, and improvement proposals :)